# Tkinter progress bar attached to function?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a function that reads in two large files and merges them, and I would like to add a progress bar using TK to show the user that the function is still running.

```
def makeDF():
    # DF SETUP---
    print("Starting dataframe creation")
    qData = pd.read_excel("fileOne.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
    yData= pd.read_excel(fileTwo.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
    allData = pd.merge(qData, yData, on=['Var1','Var2','Var3'], how="outer")
```

I have read through various threads and not found *how to link a progress bar to a function that isn't looping or incrementing anything*. I just want to start the progress bar, execute the function, have the progress bar update/show activity while the function runs, then end the progress bar when the function is complete. So far I have seen articles on threading, but they always involve some list of items that is being processed or worked through in a queue, not just one lengthy operation.

Thank you!

Comment: Even ignoring the whole event-loop-blocking issue: Where do you expect the progress/activity updates to come from? Progress bars aren't magic; they can only update when you tell them there's some progress. For example, if that `read_excel` call takes 20 seconds, your code doesn't do anything except wait for it to finish. If your code doesn't know how much progress it's made, or even if it's still making progress, then your code can't update a progress bar.

Comment: In tk, there are two types of progress bar, determinate and indeterminate one. Determinate ones must be updated, whereas indeterminate ones just continue at a set speed, restarting when they reach the end. (Correct me if I'm wrong). Choose your type, and work out how it will work: will it update after every function, etc.